# Extract NewsFeed and use in a custom user control

Tags: user, user-controls, social, newsfeed

Is it possible to use the news feed control in a custom user control page (ascx) ?

I need only the message sender part of the newsFeed, which is displayed in following picture. 
So that I could send micro posts using hashtags or mentions, and also upload pictures from my custom user control, which is going to be placed in master page.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can add the webpart programmatically:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.SiteFeedWebPart CustNewsFeedWP = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.SiteFeedWebPart();
```

then configure as you like, here is the list of members available:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.portal.webcontrols.aspx

you need to inport the sharepoint.portal dll.

to add the above code, within the ascx you should have some codebehind (.ascx.cs),

overide the onload, add the above code to the ascx and bam you have your custom news feed!